# ALL drives on MSA60 have blue UID LED lit

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-modular-smart-array

We have a pair of MSA60's connected to two different servers. Today I ran a diagnostic report via the HP Array Configuration utility in order to obtain the serial numbers of the devices.

Now that that has ran, all of the drives in the devices have their blue UID LED lit. I can't see anywhere in the config utility where that can be turned off, nor do I know why they became lit after the diagnostics.

There are no system faults or alerts on either system.

I don't have too much experience with these guys, as they've been inherited with this client.

I was unable to find an answer in the manual, or via searching the web.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try closing the ACU to see if the lights go off.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I actually logged out of the servers when I completed the diagnostics, so the ACU was closed at that time.

Comment: Wait, do you mean that the LEDs are still on, even though you don't have the ACU open on either server?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am out of the ACU, and the actually logged off of the server, yet all of the LEDs are lit. I don't think it is hurting anything, but it is puzzling.

Comment: Probably an obvious question, but is anyone else logged on with the ACU running? Maybe try logging back on, launching the ACU and seeing if clicking around in there causes the LEDs to go on and off accordingly.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thank you for the response.

Comment: Well, What I did to resolve it was to re-open the ACU and then exit properly. I had just logged off of the server and let Windows take care of closing the ACU, but I guess it doesn't close it properly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're in the ACU, the blue LEDs light up for whatever drives you've got selected in the tree on the left side.

This allows you to quickly see which drives are part of an array, or volume.

Closing the ACU will reset the lights back to their default *OFF* state.